# Issue drawing all the connectors in digital circuit

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits, electronics

I am trying to convert this digital circuit into Latex code. It is a full subtractor. I saw that in the blog there are anyone else that post the same function, but it resolves the circuit in a different form.

I've tried and at the moment I have managed to position all of the elements of the circuit, but I can't figure out how to draw all the connectors (--).

Here's the code I have so far:

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
       \begin{circuitikz}[american]
            % ~~~ placing all components ~~~~~~
            \node [xnor port] (N1) at (4.0 ,0.0) {N1};
            \node [xnor port] (N2) at (8.5,-0.3) {N2};
            \node [not port]  (I1) at (5,-1.7) {I1};
            \node [not port]  (I2) at (2.5,-2.5) {I2};
            \node [and port]  (A1) at (8.5,-2.0) {A1};
            \node [and port]  (A2) at (5.0,-3.5) {A2};
            \node [or port]   (O1) at (12.0,-3.25) {O1};
            %    some ports
            \node [ocirc] (A) at (0,0.3) {A};
            \node [ocirc] (B) at (0,-0.3) {B};
            \node [ocirc] (BI) at (6,-0.6) {$B_{in}$};
            \node [ocirc] (DI) at (13,-0.35) {Diff};
            \node [ocirc] (BO) at (13,-3.25) {$B_{out}$};
        
            % ~~~ connections ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            \draw (A) -- (N1.in 1);
            \draw (B) -- (N1.in 2);
            \draw (N1.out) -- (N2.in 1);
            \draw (N2.out) -- (DI);
            \draw (O1.out) -- (BO);
            
            \draw (I1.out) -- (A1.in 1);
            \draw (1.8,0.3) node[circ]{} |- (I2.in 1);
            \draw (1.3,-0.3) node[circ]{} |- (A2.in 2);
            \draw (N1.out) node[circ]{} |- (I1.in);
            \draw (6.5, -0.6) node[circ]{} |- (A1.in 2);
            \draw (BI) node[circ]{} -- (N2.in 2);
            \draw (I2.out) -- (A2.in 1);
            \draw (A1.out) -- (O1.in 1);
            \draw (A2.out) |- (O1.in 2);
        \end{center}
         \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the draw that I obtain is:

[image: ![circuit latex]

And the model that I am trying to replicate is:

[image: subtractor full model]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of posting a fragment of code, it's more helpful to put your code into a complete document that people can play with.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. However, if you try to copy and compile it: it won't. Please add the missing parts ...

Comment: @eng, if you made a code copy, that's ok: but please mention it. (Wr.t. to your previous code chances are slim that you'd come up with literally the same yourself ...) // May be you just rephrase your progress statement for more clarity. Thanks

Comment: Hello, sorry, it's the first time that i used this stackexchange and i don't know how to notify that i advance with my code, but i don't have the final version yet. where can i refresh the code that i obtain with your comments?

Comment: You can edit your question using the "edit" link below it. But please do not change the question substantially; in that case it's better to ask a new one. Remember, the idea of this site is that the question&answer will be useful to other user, not just to you, somite important to maintain coherence.

Answer (score 8):

Let's see if I can help you to learn how to draw the circuit --- I will not fill in the gap on your code, because I think it's quite unmaintainable.

Let's start. The best logic port shapes of `circuitikz` are the IEEE standard ones; let's use them and, moreover, let's add the *style* of filling them in light cyan. This is accomplished by

```
\ctikzset{logic ports=ieee, logic ports/fill=cyan!30}
```

(look at the *styling* part of the manual. I know it's long. Sorry, you'll probably need to read it; I assure you it took more time to write it ).

Start with one port, let's suppose the top left XNOR.

```latex
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american,RPvoltages,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{logic ports=ieee, logic ports/fill=cyan!30}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \node [xor port](X1) at (0,0) {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now let's add the input. We can start from the two inputs and move left (negative *x* displacement) to avoid the ugly steps you have in the drawing; let's say we move 3 units (by default they are centimeters). Adding

```
    \draw (X1.in 1) -- ++(-3,0) node[left, red](labelA){A};
    \draw (X1.in 2) -- ++(-3,0) node[left, red](labelB){B};
```

You have the following:

[image]

Let's go now to add the NOT port. In this case, the most convenient way is to use an `inline not` (again, look at the manual; you should read the logical port chapter fully before starting so you have an idea of what's in there). We will start a bit on the right of A, put a dot (the `node[circ]{}` thing), go down, and then add the NOT.

```
    \draw (labelA.east) ++(1,0) node[circ]{} -- ++(0,-2)
        to[inline not] ++(2,0);
```

and now you have

[image]

Well, we need an AND port at the end of the above wire, don't we? So we can put one there, *anchoring* it at the upper input; let's modify the draw above this way:

```
\draw (labelA.east) ++(1,0) node[circ]{} -- ++(0,-2)
    to[inline not] ++(2,0) node[and port, anchor=in 1](A1){};
```

to obtain:

[image]

Now let's connect to the input line. We can use the handy perpendicular movements of Ti*k*Z here:

```
 \draw (labelB.east) ++(0.5,0) node[circ]{} |- (A1.in 2);
```

where `|-` means "draw vertically, then horizontally":

[image]

Hmmm... a bit cramped here. Although the dimension of the ports follows IEEE standards, let's make the NOT a bit smaller. The full code is now:

```latex
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american,RPvoltages,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{logic ports=ieee, logic ports/fill=cyan!30}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \node [xor port](X1) at (0,0) {};
    \draw (X1.in 1) -- ++(-3,0) node[left, red](labelA){A};
    \draw (X1.in 2) -- ++(-3,0) node[left, red](labelB){B};
    \draw (labelA.east) ++(1,0) node[circ]{} -- ++(0,-2)
        to[inline not, logic ports/scale=0.8] ++(2,0)
        node[and port, anchor=in 1](A1){};
    \draw (labelB.east) ++(0.5,0) node[circ]{} |- (A1.in 2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Well, I suppose now you are able to continue by yourself. It will take (much) more time to do that than copy a solution from here, but once you get through it, you will be able to draw *any* logic circuit by yourself.

Comment: +1: Very nice mini-tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a second approach, less nice than Rmano's tutorial, following a different philosophy:

- don't do it all in one go (though you could)
- place components first
- connect second
- i.e. like you'd do in a schematic or with a PCB

The result is far from being optimal, with lots of shortcomings. If you combine it with Rmano's advice, you can obtain very clean and easy to read code.

[image: sketch]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{circuitikz}[american]
    % ~~~ placing all components ~~~~~~
    \node [xnor port] (N1) at (4.0 ,0.0) {N1};
    \node [xnor port] (N2) at (8.5,-0.3) {N2};
    \node [not port]  (I1) at (6.0,-1.5) {I1};
    \node [not port]  (I2) at (2.5,-2.5) {I2};
    \node [and port]  (A1) at (8.5,-2.0) {A1};
    \node [and port]  (A2) at (5.0,-3.5) {A2};
    \node [or port]   (O1) at (11.0,-3.5) {O1};
    %    some ports
    \node [ocirc] (A) at (0,0.3) {A};
    \node [ocirc] (B) at (0,-0.3) {B};
    \node [ocirc] (DI) at (13,-0.6) {Diff};
    \node [ocirc] (BO) at (13,-3.5) {Borrow out};

    % ~~~ connections ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw (A) -- (N1.in 1);
    \draw (B) -- (N1.in 2);
    \draw (N1.out) -- (N2.in 1);
    \draw (N2.out) -- (DI);
    \draw (O1.out) -- (BO);
    
    \draw (I1.out) -- (A1.in 1);
    \draw (I2.out) -- (A2.in 1);
    \draw (A1.out) -- (O1.in 1);
    \draw (A2.out) |- (O1.in 2);
 \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I edited my question taking into account your answer and the answer above. Can you take a look if you want. Is more or less finished, but it need some details added

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is found in the logic examples in the Circuit_macros distribution on CTAN (which requires m4 and dpic but which can produce tikz output). The following code draws a circuit implementing the function:

```
Autologix(
  Xor( Xor(A,B), Borrow);
  Or( And( Not(Xor(A,B)), Borrow), And( Not(A), B)),
  R)
```

This is strict functional notation and draws two Xor(A,B) gates. To draw the circuit with only one Xor(A,B) gate requires some tweaking:

```
    F2: Autologix(Or( And( Not(Xor(A,B)), Borrow), And( B, Not(A))),R)
      "A" wid textht at F2.InA above
      "B" wid textht at F2.InB above
      "Borrow" at F2.InBorrow+(0,3*textht) "in"
      "Borrow" wid 5*textht at F2.Out ljust "out" ljust
    F1: XOR_gate with .Out at F2.Out+(-3/2*L_unit,11*L_unit)
      line from F1.Out right 3/2*L_unit
      "Diff" wid 4*textht ljust
      line from F1.In2 to (F2.Out7,F1.In2) then to F2.Out7; dot
      dot(at F2.InBorrow+(0,-2*L_unit))
      line right_ 3*L_unit; continue to (Here,F1.In1) then to F1.In1
```

Answer (score 1):

To further confuse you, this version uses relative positioning.  With the exception of A1 (which is placed directly below N2), all the components are positioned relative to their in or out anchors.  This minimizes zig-zags and makes changing distances easier.

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{circuitikz}[american]
    \draw (0,0) node [ocirc] (A) {} node[left] {A} -- ++(1.5,0)
          node [xnor port,anchor=in 1] (N1) {N1};
    \draw (N1.in 2) -- (N1.in 2 -| A) node [ocirc] (B) {} node[left] {B};
    \draw (N1.out) -- ++(2,0) node[xnor port, anchor=in 1] (N2) {N2};
    \draw (N2.out) -- ++(1.6,0) node[ocirc] (D1) {} node[right] {Diff};
%
    \draw (N2.in 2) node[circ]{} -- ++(-0.5,0) node[ocirc]{} node[left] {B\textsubscript{in}};
    \draw (N2) ++ (0,-1.5) node[and port] (A1) {A1};
    \draw (A1.in 2) -| (N2.in 2);
    \draw (A1.in 1) -- ++(-0.5,0) node [not port, anchor=out, scale=0.7] (I1) {I1};
    \draw (I1.in) -| (N1.out) node[circ]{};
%
    \draw (D1) ++(0,-2) node [ocirc] (BO) {} node[right]{B\textsubscript{out}}
          (BO.left) node [or port, anchor=out] (O1) {O1};
    \draw (O1.in 2) -- ++(-3,0) node [and port, anchor=out] (A2) {A2};
    \draw (A2.in 1) node [not port, anchor=out, scale=0.7] (I2) {I2};
    \draw (I2.in) -| ($(A) + (1,0)$) node[circ]{};
    \draw (A2.in 2) -| ($(B) + (0.5,0)$) node[circ]{};
%
    \draw (A1.out) |- (O1.in 1);
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Nice. If you add `(BO.left)` before `node [or port, anchor=out] (O1) {O1}` you'll avoid the glitch on the open pole in B_out. But you should give a bit more horizontal space, the inputs of O1 (and I2, really) stick out a bit...

Comment: @Rmano - Thanks for (BO.left), although it adds more space than I expected.   I'll keep the short leads on A1 and I2 for compacteness and simplicity.  I'm tempted however to make O1 larger so I can lose the zig-zag.